# Finding Interior and Derived set of some set

Tags: general-topology, problem-solving, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be the set of real numbers.

- Let a topology be  $T_r$ generated by $\{(a,\infty): a$ is a real number$\}$
  I have to find the derived set of $(0,1)$ in this topology.
  My answer is $X$, as any neighborhood of any number has an intersection with $(0,1)$ other than the number.
  Also the topological space $(X, T_r)$ is not Hausdorff, I think it is not $T_1$ and also not $T_2$. Am I right?
- Let another topology on $X$ be $T_l$ , the lower limit topology.
  I have to find the interior of $(0,1]$.
  My answer is $(0,1)$.
  Are my answers right?
  If not hope to get corrected.
  Thank you.

Comment: A point is not a limit point if it has a neighborhood containing some other point in the given set, but a point whose every neighborhood contains some other point in the given set. $T_2$ is the same as Hausdorff. $(0, 1)$ cannot be interior of $(0, 1]$ in the lower limit topology since it is not open in this topology.

Comment: You're correct.  Exercise:  show T_r is T_0.

Comment: Yesss...you are right user87690..but how (0,1)is not open in lowerlimit topology? I think it is open as it is finer than the usual topology.

Comment: Here T_0 means the usual topology right? William Elliott

Comment: @HirenGarai . $T_0$ is a separation property of some topological spaces. A space $S$ is a $T_0$ space iff whenever $x,y\in S$ with $x\ne y$ there is an open set that contains one of $x,y$ but not both of them. In other words $x\not \in Cl(\{y\})\lor y\not \in Cl(\{x\}).$

Comment: @HirenGarai: I though that the lower limit topology is the one generated by intervals $(-∞, a)$, i.e. the dual topology to $T_r$. Both are coarser than the usual topology and the usual topology is their join.